# How to know if file in a loop is the last one?

Tags: bash, loops

Example

```
for FILE in $DIR/* 
do
  if(<is last File>)
    doSomethingSpecial($FILE)
  else
    doSomethingRegular($FILE)
  fi
done
```

What to call for `<is last file>` to check if the current file is the last one in the array ?

Is there an easy built-in check without checking the array's length by myself ?

Comment: No, I do not want to process the last file only, but to process each file (like in my loop example) and just do another operation on the last file.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, you can use ls + tail to detect the last file name. then in your loop check the file name -eq check. That would be the <is last> condition. I am not before my *nix console, just giving an idea

Comment: `ls | tail` will not work if the last file name contains a new line (a rare occurrence, but not impossible).

Answer (score 22):

*What to call for  to check if the current file is the last one in the array ?*

For a start, you are not using an array.  If you were then it would be easy:

```
declare -a files
files=($DIR/*)
pos=$(( ${#files[*]} - 1 ))
last=${files[$pos]}

for FILE in "${files[@]}"
do 
  if [[ $FILE == $last ]]
  then
     echo "$FILE is the last" 
     break
  else 
     echo "$FILE"
  fi 
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works fine. But I am a bit disappointed there is no somehow 'nicer' way, without the low-level steps, to do this.

Comment: Other languages, e.g. Perl and Python, allow indexing from the right with negative offsets, so the last is [-1].  Maybe you should upgrade your language to something more powerful?  Why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: Sometime in the 4.x series, `bash` began to allow negative array offsets.

Comment: @chepner: Bash 4.2 Feb. 2011

Comment: I think this solution will not work when you'd have two equal entries in the array. It is better to iterate over indexes, i.e. with `for i in \`seq 0 $pos\`` and then retrieve the file by `FILE=${files[$i]}`.

Comment: @JindraHelcl: my solution does not look at the data in the array, only the length (`${#files[*]}`), so all the entries could be equal and it should still work - unless you have an example where it doesn't?

Comment: Since you mention that "it would be easy" for arrays, I might point out that this technique doesn't *technically* work for arrays of non-unique items.  The `if [[ $FILE == $last ]]` clause will match *all* items that have the same value as the last value.  Now, since the OP is explicitly dealing with *files*, we can be reasonably certain of an array with unique values (at least within a single directory); but for generic *arrays*, you would probably want to increment a counter in the loop, and compare to `$pos`...

Comment: @jimbobmcgee: well it depends what the application wants to do with duplicates.  I agree with the gist of what you say, but your issue with the comparison is irrelevant to the question.   Looking at my code again, I should have put a `break` on a successful comparison.  (Edit)

Comment: Adding a `break` doesn't ensure it is the last item in the array; it just means that the first time a value is encountered that is the same as the last value in the array, the loop will terminate

Comment: Consider an array `ARR=( a b c d e c )`: with your previous code (i.e. without the `break`), it would result in `a, b, c is the last, d, e, c is the last` would be echoed twice.  With your current code (i.e. with the `break`), it would result in `a, b, c is the last`, but `d, e` would not be printed.  Both outcomes are technically wrong for *general* arrays (although not necessarily for *files*)

Comment: @jimbobmcgee: OK, but the question was "*What to call for <is last file> to check if the current file is the last one in the array ?*".  It does not ask for intermediate names to be printed, and it does not bother about duplicates.  You are right that my answer is not correct for a different question.

Answer (score 10):

I know of no way to tell that you are processing the last element of a list in a for loop. However you could use an array, iterate over all but the last element, and then process the last element outside the loop:

```
files=($DIR/*)
for file in "${files[@]::${#files[@]}-1}" ; do
    doSomethingRegular "$file"
done
doSomethingSpecial "${files[@]: -1:1}"
```

The expansion `${files[@]:offset:length}` evaluates to all the elements starting at `offset` (or the beginning if empty) for `length` elements. `${#files[@]}-1` is the number of elements in the array minus 1.

`${files[@]: -1:1}` evaluates to the last element - -1 from the end, length 1. The space is necessary as `:-` is treated differently to `: -`.

Comment: Starting with `bash` 4.x (not sure if 4.0 or a later point release), you can use `${files[-1]}` instead of `${files[@]: -1:1}`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
LAST_FILE=""
for f in *
do
        if [ ! -z $LAST_FILE ]
        then
                echo "Process file normally $LAST_FILE"
        fi
        LAST_FILE=$f
done
if [ ! -z $LAST_FILE ]
then
        echo "Process file as last file $LAST_FILE"
fi
```

Produces

```
bash[1051]: ls
1  2  3  4
bash[1052]: sh ../last_file.sh
Process file normally 1
Process file normally 2
Process file normally 3
Process file as last file 4
```

Comment: This will only process the first file normally.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your code carefully enough. I think I missed that you weren't working directly on `$f`, but on `$LAST_FILE`.

Comment: @GregReynolds: I love this solution - simply using "phase shift" variable. It's simple, portable and can be used as one-liner :) Thanks for sharing. For completeness my one liner: `( ff="" ; for f in * ; do [  -n "$ff" ] && echo normal: $ff ; ff=$f ; done ; echo last: $ff )`

Answer (score 4):

Building on the current highest-voted answer from @cdarke (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298757/415523), if looking at a general array of values (rather than specifically files on disk), the loop code would be as follows:

```
declare -a array
declare -i length current

array=( a b c d e c )
length=${#array[@]}
current=0

for VALUE in "${array[@]}"; do 
  current=$((current + 1))

  if [[ "$current" -eq "$length" ]]; then
     echo "$VALUE is the last" 
  else 
     echo "$VALUE"
  fi 
done
```

This yields the output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
c is the last
```

This ensures that only the *last* item in the array triggers the alternative action and that, if any other item in the array duplicates the last value, the alternative action is *not* called for the earlier duplicates.

In the case of an array of paths to *files* in a specific directory, e.g.

```
array=( $DIR/* )
```

...it is probably less of a concern, since individual filenames within the same directory are almost-certainly unique (unless you have a *really* odd filesystem!)

Comment: Yet not very clean, but a simple solution that works, even with non-consecutive (holes between indexes) arrays. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use find to find the total number of files.
 Then when you are in the loop count to the total number and carry out your task when the total equals the count i.e, the last file.

```
 f=0
tot_files=`find  . -iname '*.txt' | wc -l`
 for FILE in $DIR/* 
do 
f=($f+1)
if [[ $f == $tot_files ]];then
carryout your task
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse the positional parameters, since they act similarly to an array,
but are a little easier to manipulate. You should either save the old positional
parameters, or execute in a subshell.

```
# Method 1: use a subshell. Slightly cleaner, but you can't always
# do this (for example, you may need to affect variables in the current
# shell
files=( $DIR/* )

(
    set -- "${files[@]}"
    until (( $# == 1 )); do
        doSomethingRegular "$1"
        shift
    done    
    doSomethingSpecial "$1"
)

# Method 2: save the positional parameters. A bit uglier, but
# executes everything in the same shell.

files=( $DIR/* )
oldPP=( "$@" )
set -- "${files[@]}"
until (( $# == 1 )); do
    doSomethingRegular "$1"
    shift
done    
doSomethingSpecial "$1"
set -- "${oldPP[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

What makes a file *the last one*? Is there something special about it? Is it the file with the greatest name when sorted by name?

Maybe you can take the file names *backwards*. Then, it's the first file you want to treat special and not the last. figuring out the first is a much easier task than doing the last:

```
for file in $(ls -r1 $dir)
do
    if [ ! $processedLast ] 
    then
        doSomethingSpecial($file)
        processedLast=1
    else
        doSomethingRegular($file)
    fi
done
```

No arrays needed. Actually, I like [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12299952/368630)'s answer about using positional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's old question - but building on answer from @GregReynolds please use this one-liner if commands differ only by parameters on last pass. Ugly, ugly code for one-liner lovers

`( ff="" ; for f in * "" ; do [ -n "$ff" ] && echo $(${f:+false} && echo $ff alternate params here || echo normal params $ff ) ; ff=$f ; done )`

`normal params 1
normal params 2
normal params 3
4 alternate params here`